# Download onedrive file content in bytes using rest api?

Tags: rest, onedrive

I have web application to send email from OneDrive location. I have obtained a user consent and access token from Ms Live site. I am trying to implement process where user clicks on 'browse' button, they should see list of files which are in onedrive. User selects file from there and clicks on 'Send Email' button in web page which should invoke the downloading of selected file silently and send that to email address provided by user.
At the moment onedrive sends download link to get file content. Does anyone knows how to get file content in bytes using REST API as I don't want the user to download the file in their local machine. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you plan on sending the selected OneDrive file as an attachment in email (right?). This could be tricky if you don't want the file to be downloaded locally.

Maybe you could consider [sending a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659731.aspx#get_links_to_files_and_folders) to the selected OneDrive file in the email instead. This way, the email recipient will be able to download the file directly from the sender's OneDrive.